# Overwriting cells in django export

Tags: python, django

I have this code in my views.py. This is a function that exports data from a table to an excel file:

```
for facturas in form:
     data = {
             "Cliente": facturas.nombre_cliente,
             "Fecha de Factura":facturas.fecha_factura,
             "Tipo de Factura": facturas.tipo_Factura,
             }

      for column, key in enumerate(header, start=1):
          sheet.write(1, column, str(data[key]), body_style)


      response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
      response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = "report.xls"'
      book.save(response)

return response
```

"form" is a queryset that contains the files selected by the user to export.

What is happenning is that if i choose to export 2 or more files i´m only getting the information of one.

Maybe this is because i´m overwriting the cells but i ´ve tried to modify this and nothing change. How can i write the information in different rows of an excel file?

Any advice will be really apreciatted. Thanks

**EDIT**

This is how i display the items in the table:

```
{% for factura in facturas %}
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fa fa-file"> <a href="{% url 'ver_Factura' factura.pk %}">Ver</a></i>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="factura" value="{{ factura.pk }}">
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>{{ factura.nombre_cliente }}</td>
        <td>{{ factura.numero_De_Factura }}</td>
        <td>{{ factura.fecha_factura }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And this is wrapped in a form:

```
<form action="{% url 'descarga'%}" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {% csrf_token %}
...

    <input type="submit" name="_download" value="Descargar" id="buttonDescargar" class="btnDescargar"> 

</form>
```

**EDIT 2**

This is how i´m instantiating the form:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Factura.objects.filter(id__in=selected_values)
    print form
```

with "print form" i´m checking that form has the values that i selected in the table.

Comment: What do you think this line is doing on the second and later iterations of your main `for` loop? `response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')`

Comment: i see what you are saying. I have to save all the iterations and then create the response right?

Comment: Or create the response first. As it is you are building multiple responses and only using the last.

Comment: I´m a noob in python can you explain a little more? i would really appreciatte it

Comment: See my answer - the point is to construct only a single response, but it doesn't matter where in the view you do so as long as it exists by the time you return it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to write the values from each element of your `facturas` iterable to different rows, then return one response:

```
for (rownum, facturas) in enumerate(form, start=1):
     data = {
             "Cliente": facturas.nombre_cliente,
             "Fecha de Factura":facturas.fecha_factura,
             "Tipo de Factura": facturas.tipo_Factura,
             }

      for column, key in enumerate(header, start=1):
          sheet.write(rownum, column, str(data[key]), body_style)


response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = "report.xls"'
book.save(response)

return response
```

You could also build the empty `response` before the for loop, that makes no difference:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = "report.xls"'

for (rownum, facturas) in enumerate(form, start=1):
     data = {
             "Cliente": facturas.nombre_cliente,
             "Fecha de Factura":facturas.fecha_factura,
             "Tipo de Factura": facturas.tipo_Factura,
             }

      for column, key in enumerate(header, start=1):
          sheet.write(rownum, column, str(data[key]), body_style)



book.save(response)

return response
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer,but i´m still receiving the value of only one file. I placed the
    book.save(response)
Inside the For loop and outside and it always return one value

Comment: `book.save` should be done once, after you've iterated through the form. Are you sure your form is correct?

Comment: I just added a little code that i have on my template. My table and form that contains that table.

Comment: How are you instantiating `form` in your view, I meant. You say it's a queryset - what's the query?

Comment: How are you getting `selected_values`?

Comment: This is how i´m getting selected values:     selected_values = request.POST.getlist('factura')

Comment: In that case, it generally looks OK to me. I would put a pdb break point in the view, run the development server, and see what's going wrong.